# PHP file_put_contents new line

Tags: php, line-endings

I tried use file_put_contents output new page. but I meet some trouble in breaking new line.

```
<?php
$data ='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\r\n';
$data .='<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">\r\n';
$data .='<head>\r\n';
$data .='</head>\r\n';
$data .='<body>\r\n';
$data .='<p>put something here</p>\r\n';
$data .='</body>\r\n';
$data .='</html>\r\n';
file_put_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . '/new.php', $data);
?>
```

I tried `\n` or `\r\n`, they all can not make a new line:

```
1. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">\r\n<head>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<p>put something here</p>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n
```

Comment: Why are you writing an HTML file with a .php extension? I mean, it's a legal PHP file, but it just seems weird.

Comment: For such uses you might also want to investigate ["HEREDOC" strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) in the manual.

Comment: @Zecc, I writing an HTML file with a `.php` for I would include `page munu` and `page footer` in it.

Comment: Alright, makes sense, but... why are you writing the file *in code* instead of just having the file already there?

Comment: @Zecc, For some static pages, reduce the database read, just creat one time.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using `\r` or `\n` in single quotes carries it literally. use double quotes instead like "\r\n"

So one line might become:

```
$data .= "<head>\r\n";
```

or

```
$data .='<head>' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using [single-quoted character literals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), which don't interpret escape sequences.
Either switch to double-quoted strings or, preferably, use [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```
<?php
$data = <<<CONTENTS
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>put something here</p>
</body>
</html>
CONTENTS;
file_put_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . '/new.php', $data);
?>
```

But really, why are you writing a hard-coded file? That's really strange.

Comment: This is also a better method.

Comment: but `"HEREDOC" strings` hardly be broken, if I need some php processing in it, like `if... else...`